# Построение нескольких осей Y в d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли в d3js возможность построение нескольких шкал по Y.
Нужно вывести в графике количество продаж, дату, и среднюю цену на эту дату. 
ПО X идет одна шкала - дата.
НА графике отрисовываются 2 линии - одна отвечает за количество продаж, другая за среднюю цену.
Так вот Одна шкала по Y показывает количество продаж, а нужна еще одна дополнительная с ценами.

Answer (score 0):

В общем проблему решил так:
Создал дополнительную ось Y методом d3.scaleLinear():

```
var scaleYPrice = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([400000 , 0])
        .range([0, yAxisLength]);
```

Скрыл ее стилями при отрисовке:

```
svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y-axis-price")
        .style('display','none')
        .attr("transform",
            "translate(" + margin + "," + margin + ")")
        .call(yAxisPrice);
```

И отрисовал дополнительную линию с данными:

```
 g.append("path")
        .attr("d", line(dataPrice))
        .style("stroke", "blue")
        .style("stroke-width", 2);
```

UPD: Вот тут еще хорошо описывается создание графика:
https://habrahabr.ru/post/303834/